# Why fopen return invalid handle when server returns error

Tags: php, http

When server return any error (401, 405, etc.), fopen return invalid.
Is there a way to receive the body of the response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a context (via [stream_context_create](http://php.net/stream_context_create)) and the [ignore_errors context option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), that "*Fetch the content even on failure status codes.*":

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true,
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$handle = fopen('http://url/', 'r', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, use the cURL extension instead. Faster performance, finer-grained controls over its behavior, as well as more powerful - you'd be able to retrieve the exact HTTP status code in this cast.

Here's a good example: http://php.net/curl.examples-basic

Here's the full documentation: http://php.net/book.curl